# Docker is making extra images

Tags: docker

When i run my `docker-compose up -d` command it runs all cool buuut it creates a lot of images i dont know if this should be a normal behavior but it looks like this

```
Status: Downloaded newer image for node:11.1.0
 ---> 4e4c445311e6
Step 2/8 : RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
 ---> Running in 3b78051548b7
Removing intermediate container 3b78051548b7
 ---> 96e53f58ca4a
Step 3/8 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Running in 6c09aca5e321
Removing intermediate container 6c09aca5e321
 ---> a392a2bdd279
Step 4/8 : ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
 ---> Running in 9443cc34dc2a
Removing intermediate container 9443cc34dc2a
 ---> 6ba4c2ed0014
```

As you can see it makes a new image each step

Here you can see the list of the images made by the command

```
somethinghere_somethinghere   latest              4163a2ac78cc        14 minutes ago      1.23GB
<none>                              <none>              2af2d216914a        14 minutes ago      1.23GB
<none>                              <none>              2471e3d94378        15 minutes ago      1.11GB
<none>                              <none>              6ba4c2ed0014        15 minutes ago      894MB
<none>                              <none>              71141d30cec8        15 minutes ago      894MB
<none>                              <none>              a392a2bdd279        15 minutes ago      894MB
<none>                              <none>              96e53f58ca4a        15 minutes ago      894MB
```

Here ill show you my docker-compose and dockerfile

Dockerfile

```
# base image
FROM node:11.1.0

# set working directory
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add `/usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@1.1.1 -g --silent

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

docker-compose

```
version: '3.5'

services:

  somethinghere:
    container_name: somethinghere-client
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - '.:/usr/src/app'
      - '/usr/src/app/node_modules'
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Many <none> images created after build a docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48745936/many-none-images-created-after-build-a-docker-image)

Comment: The short answer is "don't use the `-a` option to `docker images`, it shows you details you usually don't care about".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's docker's caching mechanism working, they help the system to build faster if there are minor changes in the dockerfile.

As you can see in the build output,

```
Step 2/8 : RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
 ---> Running in 3b78051548b7
Removing intermediate container 3b78051548b7
 ---> 96e53f58ca4a
```

Creates a layer with the image 96e53f58ca4a.

Normally you won't need to worry about them, just use `docker images` and you won't see them.

More reading [here](http://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2015/07/what-are-docker-none-none-images/)