# How do I use the same python image for several docker containers?

Tags: docker

I have a few python services running in docker. My dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.6-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["python", "-u", "app.py"]
```

When I run "docker images -a" command, I can see that each service has its own python parent image:

[image]

Is it really so? How do I change dockerfiles to make different services use the same image? Do I need to use docker-compose?

Comment: The list you provide is the restult of "docker images". You can have several images of the same service, but eventually, what will be used is the latest one with the matching tag (others will be untaged). Try to do a clean "pull", first, to ensure the latest one is ok, and then rereun your services, and show the "docker ps"  output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Many <none> images created after build a docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48745936/many-none-images-created-after-build-a-docker-image)

Comment: `docker images -a` shows one line per line in your Dockerfile and you usually don't care.  Compare with `docker history`.  You are correctly sharing the `python:3.6-slim` base image most likely, and those images are probably the Python base plus your (small) application source.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I can delete intermediate images with

```
docker save --output image.tar ImageID-or-Name
docker image prune -fa
docker load --input image.tar
```

I think this is what I need